# Finding/Calculating Thermal Conductivity of Magnesite

Tags: thermodynamics, minerals

Our research group is having a very difficult time locating anything about the thermal conductivity of $\ce{MgCO3}$. It is a pretty commonly mineral, so we were pretty surprised by this. Is any way to derive thermal conductivity from other properties of magnesium carbonate? (Magnesite)

Comment: Search for the thermal conductivity of magnesite.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We had been trying that, but all the sites that list the thermal conductivity of magnesite say that it is made mostly out of $\ce{MgO}$, not $\ce{MgCO3}$. (Example: brick, magnesite (mgo 87) https://www.thermtest.com/material-property-search)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [dissertation](http://www.diss.fu-berlin.de/diss/servlets/MCRFileNodeServlet/FUDISS_derivate_000000002218/02_Kapitel_2.pdf) of K. Kratz (2006) the following values of thermal diffusivity along the crystallographic axes of magnesite are listed:

$D_{[001]} = 6.55 ~\mathrm{mm^2\,s^{-1}}$,
$D_{[100]} = 2.38 ~\mathrm{mm^2\,s^{-1}}$,
$D_{[010]} = 2.38 ~\mathrm{mm^2\,s^{-1}}$.

Ch. Clauser and E. Huenges, [Thermal Conductivity of Rocks and Minerals](https://www.allbeton.ru/upload/mediawiki/bb3/thermal-conductivity-of-rocks-and-minerals.pdf) lists the following values for the thermal conductivity of magnesite in the temperature range from 25-100°C:

$\lambda_{\perp} = 7.32 \pm 0.57 ~\mathrm{W m^{-1} K^{-1}}$
$\lambda_{\mid} = 7.86 \pm 0.17 ~\mathrm{W m^{-1} K^{-1}}$

Comment: Thank you! The references you have listed are great. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/thermal-conductivity-d_429.html

at 25 celcius the thermal conductivity is 4.15 W/m/K

Comment: Thank you. How can we be sure that this refers to a brick made out of $\ce{MgCO3}$ and not $\ce{MgO}$? Most of the websites I have seen that list a similar thermal conductivity have been calling $\ce{MgO}$ bricks magnesite. (Example above).